# PHP 5 intval() as undefined function?

Tags: php, ajax

I have used Ajax to combine Javascript and PHP (vers. 5.4) and I was confronted with an error of the simple function intval().

```
13: intval($_POST["request"]);
```

The output said:

> **Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function  intval() in **[...]/ajax/request.php** on line **13**

I have really no idea, 'cause the PHP Manual [here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.intval.php) tell me that the function must be exists.

Comment: Are you getting any other warnings or errors? Does the request parameter exist?

Comment: What does `var_dump(function_exists('intval'));` output?

Comment: If you cut/pasted that error, then you appear to have some non-visible character immediately before intval that could be being treated as part of the function name

Comment: 1th quest.: No there aren't any other warnings or errors and the parameter exists.

Comment: 2th quest.: The output says: `bool(true)` -> ??? I have forgot to say that I use the function in an if-Condition: `if (intval($_POST["request"]) == 1 || intval($_POST["request"]) == 3) {...}`

Comment: Additionally this error only occurs if `$_POST["request"]` has a value of `3`.